# Unambiguous Context free grammar for strings in {a,b}* containing at least as many a's as b's

Tags: context-free-grammar

Taken from Sipser, 2.28.

I came up with the following:

$$S \rightarrow \epsilon|aS|bAs$$
$$A \rightarrow a|bAA$$

I believe this grammar generates the mentioned language, but I am not sure how to check that it does so unambiguously.
Any hints?

Comment: What are some strings of the language? I do not understand "At least". If there are as many $a$'s as $b$'s then there cannot be more $a$'s than $b$'s or viceversa.

Comment: for example aab, ab, a, aaababa, etc. The number of a's in the string is equal or more than the number of b's